# Primefaces 3.0.M3 namespace url doesn't work

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I read that the new namespace for Primefaces 3.0.M3 is `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"` but doesn't work. Netbeans throws `No library found for this namespace` error. If I go back to the old namespace, the new components aren't rendered.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [taglib uri was changed](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1431) from `http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui` to `http://primefaces.org/ui` some time after the M3 release, between `3.0.RC1-SNAPSHOT` and `3.0.M4-SNAPSHOT`. The latest released version seems to be M3 and is still using the old namespace. I would suggest to use the snapshot versions until the next milestone or final version is released, in order to already work with the new namespace and avoid changes at a later stage.

In my opinion the snapshots are mostly stable. They are available in the [primefaces maven repo](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1429), maybe you have to configure the repository entry in your pom to [allow snapshot versions](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories).

Comment: But the primefaces site points to 3.0.M3 as the latest release. There is a 3.0.M4 release?

Comment: But what if I don't have a pom.xml? I don't use Maven...It's Java Web App in Netbeans

Comment: You can download the jar files directly from the primefaces repository (http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces/), or you could check out the trunk from their subversion (http://primefaces.googlecode.com/svn/primefaces/trunk) and build that.

Answer (score 3):

3.0.M3 and before = http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui

3.0.M4(not released yet, applies to snapshots now) and future = http://primefaces.org./ui

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete from web.xml the Resource Servlet:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
```

and

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primefaces_resource/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```